# Terminal Hacks to Manually Transfer Ipod Music To Computer

Tags: terminal, itunes

I need to transfer a clients ipod music to a new computer and in to a new Itunes library. As you know, Apple does not allow you to reverse sync music from an Ipod to an itunes library as this would breed a long lineage of media piracy amongst music pirates.

On any idevice, the music folder is hidden and not typically available to the average laymen. But here at Super user we are anything but laymen.

Are there terminal hacks available that would allow me to mount the disk on the ipod and locate the hidden music folder in order to transfer to a new computer/music library? I know there are apps out there that do this but they are limited, plus its just more boss this way.

Thanks to anyone who has experience with this problem.

Comment: What version of iPod are you talking about here?  It was pretty easy on older HDD based models.  I think you are SOL, if you are talking about an iPod Touch.  No idea about the shuffle or others.

Comment: What operating system?